# Python Twitter API program returns error code 403: Forbidden

Tags: python, twitter, http-status-code-403, error-code

I am a beginner working through the python basics course on Freecodecamp.com. I am using Mac OS, python3.10.

I am trying to connect to twitter's API using an http request, gather data and then parse that data.

I made a twitter developer account and got my keys and tokens and all that stuff.

Here is a [link](https://www.py4e.com/html3/13-web) to the exact problem I am working through (scroll down to where it says "Application 2: Twitter" in bold).

Here is the code I am trying to run:

```
import urllib.request, urllib.parse, urllib.error
import twurl
import ssl


# https://apps.twitter.com/
# Create App and get the four strings, put them in hidden.py

TWITTER_URL = 'https://api.twitter.com/1.1/statuses/user_timeline.json'

# Ignore SSL certificate errors
ctx = ssl.create_default_context()
ctx.check_hostname = False
ctx.verify_mode = ssl.CERT_NONE

while True:
    print('')
    acct = input('Enter Twitter Account:')
    if (len(acct) < 1): break
    url = twurl.augment(TWITTER_URL,
                        {'screen_name': acct, 'count': '2'})
    print('Retrieving', url)
    connection = urllib.request.urlopen(url, context=ctx)
    data = connection.read().decode()
    print(data[:250])
    headers = dict(connection.getheaders())
    # print headers
    print('Remaining', headers['x-rate-limit-remaining'])
```

And here is the error that code returns:

```
Enter Twitter Account:drchuck
Retrieving https://api.twitter.com/1.1/statuses/user_timeline.json?oauth_consumer_key=9uxUyq33IRxCL5CZf7LyfubX3&oauth_timestamp=1641148177&oauth_nonce=80764354&oauth_version=1.0&screen_name=drchuck&count=2&oauth_token=1423673018467983360-Tg6vMoRAWO7FCgnGKhz9WgrPUoCsZa&oauth_signature_method=HMAC-SHA1&oauth_signature=C%2FQIvEhgZ8AQQooC4E%2BekJSZwjE%3D
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/jguinn/env/twtr-api-demo/twitter1.py", line 23, in <module>
    connection = urllib.request.urlopen(url, context=ctx)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/urllib/request.py", line 216, in urlopen
    return opener.open(url, data, timeout)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/urllib/request.py", line 525, in open
    response = meth(req, response)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/urllib/request.py", line 634, in http_response
    response = self.parent.error(
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/urllib/request.py", line 563, in error
    return self._call_chain(*args)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/urllib/request.py", line 496, in _call_chain
    result = func(*args)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/urllib/request.py", line 643, in http_error_default
    raise HTTPError(req.full_url, code, msg, hdrs, fp)
urllib.error.HTTPError: HTTP Error 403: Forbidden
```

I went on the Twitter developer website to look for [information about response codes](https://developer.twitter.com/en/support/twitter-api/error-troubleshooting) and Twitter says that 403: Forbidden codes means that:

> "The request is understood, but it has been refused or access is not
> allowed. An accompanying error message will explain why."

As a solution they suggest:

> "Check that your developer account includes access to the endpoint
> you’re trying to use. You may also need to get your App allowlisted
> (e.g. Engagement API or Ads API) or sign up for access."

I am not really sure what any of this means. Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: First, now that you’ve posted your OAuth token publicly on this website, revoke it immediately and create a new one.

Comment: oh right. thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if you resolved the issue yet but here's how I did it.

You have to go on your developer portal on twitter and apply for Elevated access. It's a pretty smooth process and once you've done that you'll be good.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is not with the code, the code is absolutely right.

Step one: Sign up for a developer account on Twitter

Step two: upgrade it to Elevated Access (it's free)

Step three: After that generate APT Key, API Secret, Access Token, and Acess Token Secret

The only thing you have to change is the consumer_key, consumer_secret, token_key, and token_secret in the hidden.py file. (consumer_key = API Key, consumer_secret = API Key Secret, token_key = Access Token, and token_secret = Access Token Secret)

Comment: The thing I did wrong was, that I first generated API keys then upgraded for elevated, and still I was using the old API keys. So, it was not working for me. So, I have to delete my application, create a new one, then have to generate new API keys. Now, I am good to go :)